# Does Flutter's google_sign_in package include a way to retrieve the user's first and last name?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am integrating **Google Sign In** into my flutter app using the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#-readme-tab-) package, and I notice that once the user logs in, you are able to see a display name, but not a first and last name:

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
    await googleSignIn.signIn();

final name = googleSignInAccount.displayName; // exists
final firstName = googleSignInAccount.givenName; // does not exist
final lastName = googleSignInAccount.familyName; // does not exist
```

I also noticed that the Android and iOS libraries for **Google Sign In** do include the `givenName` and `familyName` fields, but for some reason it is left out of the flutter library.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to retrieve these fields using an additional api call?

*Note: Please do not respond saying to just split the display name into parts via* `googleSignInAccount.displayName.split(" ");`*. This is not a solution since the display name is not always the user's full name, or the display name may be more than 2 words.*

Answer (score 8):

I found that these values can be extracted from the id token retrieved in the authentication step below:

```
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
final idToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;
```

Create a method for parsing the JWT token into a Map:

```
static Map<String, dynamic> parseJwt(String token) {
  // validate token
  if (token == null) return null;
  final List<String> parts = token.split('.');
  if (parts.length != 3) {
    return null;
  }
  // retrieve token payload
  final String payload = parts[1];
  final String normalized = base64Url.normalize(payload);
  final String resp = utf8.decode(base64Url.decode(normalized));
  // convert to Map
  final payloadMap = json.decode(resp);
  if (payloadMap is! Map<String, dynamic>) {
    return null;
  }
  return payloadMap;
}
```

From here, the `given_name` and `family_name` are easily retrievable:

```
Map<String, dynamic> idMap = parseJwt(idToken);

final String firstName = idMap["given_name"];
final String lastName = idMap["family_name"];
```

Comment: This works. Why couldn't this information just be exposed normally?